# Stacking elements vertically first, dynamic number of columns

Tags: css, alignment

When you usually insert items into DIV with constant width, they are stacked horizontally, then vertically, height changes.

```
El1  El2  El3  El4  El5
El6  El7  El8  El9  El10
El11 El12 El13
```

I want to insert my items into DIV with constant height, they should be stacked vertically, then horizontally, width should change.

```
El1  El6  El11
El2  El7  El12
El3  El8  El13
El4  El9  
El5  El10
```

I am aware of column-count property. But I don't know the number of columns in advance. I want the container to realign, when new items are added or the height changes. Its width should change. There will be another element on the right side.

Is it possible to do it using CSS, without JS?

Answer (score 2):

Here `display:flex` can do the trick;

Use following css:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvc3zj76/1/)**

Comment: Hey, thank you very much!  How can I make dynamic width? My current structure looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uvc3zj76/2/  but when you uncomment height:350px , it keeps the original width.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be more complicated than I thought. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507397

Comment: @IvanKuckir height must be fixed. Else it will take 100%. And not move to horizontal.

Comment: I need the container to be as narrow as possible, depending on the content. I need to put another element on the right side.